# Unbagging a dataset in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rdd, bigdata

I have a dataset that looks like this.

```
(34521658, 0001-01-01, 2500-01-01, 2 , A, Y, 15, P, A, 4776, 4776, 4776, {(11, P, A, 4776,4766, 4776), (12, P, A, 4776,4766, 4776), (13, P, A, 4776,4766, 4776)})
```

And now I want to un-bag to make it look like

```
(34521658, 0001-01-01, 2500-01-01, 2 , A, Y, 15, P, A, 4776, 4776, 4776, 11, P, A, 4776,4766, 4776)    
(34521658, 0001-01-01, 2500-01-01, 2 , A, Y, 15, P, A, 4776, 4776, 4776, 12, P, A, 4776,4766, 4776)
(34521658, 0001-01-01, 2500-01-01, 2 , A, Y, 15, P, A, 4776, 4776, 4776, 13, P, A, 4776,4766, 4776)
```

.

How to do this in pyspark?

Comment: Take a look at `rdd.flatMap` or `explode` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment flatMap or explode can be used. Here is how you can do it using explode sql function (explode, like the name says, it will expand an array or map column into more rows)
I will keep only the meaningful columns for the sake of simplifying the approach. Assuming that the first column is an id and the columns that you want to explode is named bag, here is how it look the initial dataset

```
+--------+--------------------+
|      id|                 bag|
+--------+--------------------+
|34521658|[[11,P,A,4776,476...|
+--------+--------------------+
```

The schema for the dataset is :

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- bag: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _4: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _5: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _6: integer (nullable = true)
```

Note that the bag column is an array of elements. On that colum we can apply explode function like this:

```
df.withColumn("bag", explode($"bag"))
```

The resulting dataset/dataframe is:

```
+--------+--------------------+
|      id|                 bag|
+--------+--------------------+
|34521658|[11,P,A,4776,4766...|
|34521658|[12,P,A,4776,4766...|
|34521658|[13,P,A,4776,4766...|
+--------+--------------------+
```

Hope it helps